# Objetos no preparados para el for de rango ¿cómo adaptarlos?

Tags: c++, bucle-for

El bucle `for` de rango de C++ es un [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) de un bucle `for` tradicional, de hecho puede consultarse la implementación en el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 6.5.4 El bucle `for` de rango
>
> 1. Dado un bucle `for` de la forma
>
>    ```
>    for ( declaracion-bucle-for : expresion ) cuerpo
>    ```
>
>    [...] el cuerpo del bucle `for` de rango equivale a:
>
>    ```
>    {
>      auto && __range = inicializador-de-rango;
>      for ( auto __begin = expresion-inicio,
>                 __end = expresion-fin;
>            __begin != __end;
>            ++__begin ) {
>        declaracion-bucle-for = *__begin;
>        statement
>      }
>    }
>    ```
>
>    1.3 [...] *expresion-inicio* y *expresion-fin* son `begin(__range)` y `end(__range)`, respectivamente, en que `begin`
>      y `end` son buscadas en los espacios de nombres asociados (3.4.2). [ *Nota:* No se hace una búsqueda ordinaria no cualificada (3.4.1). —*fin de la nota* ]

---

Sabiendo esto, hay ciertos elementos de C++ que conceptualmente deberían funcionar con el `for` de rango, como el [`std::multimap::equal_range`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range):

```
using mmii = std::multimap<int, int>;

mmii data { {0, 0}, {0, 1},  {5, 0}, {5, 1}, };

int main()
{
    // Deberia imprimir 0 1, pero falla al compilar...
    for (auto &v : data.equal_range(5)) std::cout << v.second << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo el código anterior no funciona porque el retorno de [`std::multimap::equal_range`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) es un [`std::pair`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) que contiene dos iteradores al inicio y al final del rango, el `std::pair` no dispone de `begin` y `end`, pero si los proporcionamos debería funcionar ¿no?:

```
using mmii = std::multimap<int, int>;

mmii::iterator begin(std::pair<mmii::iterator, mmii::iterator> &r) { return r.first; }
mmii::iterator end(std::pair<mmii::iterator, mmii::iterator> &r) { return r.second; }

mmii data { {0, 0}, {0, 1},  {5, 0}, {5, 1}, };

int main()
{
    // Deberia imprimir 0 1, pero falla al compilar...
    // ... las funciones begin y end no han sido usadas!
    for (auto &v : data.equal_range(5)) std::cout << v.second << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

El error obtenido es bastante complejo (según el compilador se despliega en múltiples líneas de complejos errores de plantilla) pero en resumen viene a decir que no se pueden encontrar funciones `begin` y `end` válidas.

Pensé que emplazar las funciones `begin` y `end` en un lugar accesible desde el bucle `for` de rango bastaría pero ya veo que me equivocaba.

---

¿Dónde debería situar las funciones `begin` y `end` para que el bucle `for` de rango las pueda usar?

Comment: Has errado el concepto; el `range-based for statement`, que traduces como `bucle for de rango` opera sobre un rango de valores (los elementos de un array, de un contenedor o en una `braced-init-list`), mientras que el par de iteradores que devuelve `equal_range()` sólo indica un rango de valores.

Comment: Lo se @asdasdasd , por eso añado unas funciones `begin` y `end` que transforman el par te iteradores devuelto por `equal_range` en los iteradores que toca respectivamente.

Comment: Ah, lo veo. Bueno, nada entonces. Ah, de nuevo, sólo una pregunta; ¿has considerado la posibilidad pasar de este `azúcar sintáctico` y considerar en su lugar `for_each`?

Comment: @asdasdasd hace tiempo que tengo varias soluciones alternativas para la duda planteada en la pregunta. Pero mi problema no es dar con otras soluciones (que ya tengo) si no entender el por qué sucede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La implementación de `begin` y `end` deberían estar en el espacio de nombres `std` para poder sobrecargar correctamente las implementaciones ya existentes de `std::begin` y `std::end`.

Además, los iteradores, para tu caso particular deberían ser constantes, ya que `data.equal_range` es un `rValue`.

El código debería quedar así:

```
namespace std
{
  mmii::const_iterator begin(const std::pair<mmii::iterator, mmii::iterator> &r) { return r.first; }
  mmii::const_iterator end(const std::pair<mmii::iterator, mmii::iterator> &r) { return r.second; }
}
```

Comment: ¿No está prohibido (desaconsejado) añadir símbolos al espacio de nombres `std`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No estás añadiendo símbolos sino que estás definiendo sobrecargas a funciones plantilla que ya existen. Es como cuando necesitas añadir hash a tus propios tipos (para usarlos en `std::multimap`, por ejemplo)... tienes que meter las sobrecargas en `std` para que funcionen.

Comment: Buen punto. Pero mi escepticismo aún me frena. ¿Tienes documentación/artículos/ejemplos/GotW que relacione añadir sobrecargas en el espacio de nombres `std` con buenas prácticas?

Comment: Te vale [este ejemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)?? es lo primero que he encontrado buscando

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster [Otro ejempo](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/user-defined-hash-functions-for-unordere/231600210) sacado de DrDoobs (ver página 4)

Comment: Un ejemplo en Español sería ideal para la comunidad ;) e incluso mejor algo diferente al `std::hash` ya que parece que el único ejemplo válido sea `std::hash` y el resto quede en *territorio desconocido*.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55290/discussion-between-eferion-and-paperbirdmaster).